# Angular call to Web Api 404 error The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am developing a back-end Web API application which should be called by an angular front-end application. 
When I try to make request from the angular application in order to get info about the currently logged in user I receive an error:

GET http://localhost:57693/api/Users/me 404 (Not Found)

with massage:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error."

Here is my calling javascript function from the angular's project:

```
function requestUserProfile() {
            var userProfileDeferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(BASE_URL + 'Users/me')
                .then(function (loggedInUser) {
                        currentUser = loggedInUser;
                        deferred.resolve(currentUser);
                        userProfileDeferred.resolve();
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                        $location.path('/');
                    });

            return userProfileDeferred.promise;
        }
```

where `BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:57693/api/';`.

The c# controller in Web API project is the following:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUsersService _service;

    public UsersController()
    {
        this._service = new UsersService();
    }

    // GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("me")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\In.txt", "");
        var viewModel = this._service.GetCurrentUser();

        return this.Ok(viewModel);
    }
}
```

I also had made the following configuration in

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.Indent    = true;
        ConfigureMapper();
    }
}
```

in order to put WebApiConfig.Register before RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes).

WebApiConfig has the following structure:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I also have made the following changes in Web.config file:

```
<configSections>
....

<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
</configSections>

.............

<connectionStrings>
<add name="IssueTrackingSystem" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=IssueTrackingSystem;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<httpModules>
.....

<add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
</httpModules>

...................

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        .................................

        <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

.............................
    <rewriter>
        <redirect url="~/Default.aspx" to="~/Default" />
        <redirect url="~/Login.aspx" to="~/Login" />
    </rewriter>
</configuration>
```

When I try to make a request, it doesn't reach the c# controller although the route, in my opinion, is correct.
Does someone have an idea where is the problem and how could I fix it in order to make valid request from the angular app to the WebAPI application?

The angular application had been used before with another WebAPI and worked correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have just found where is the problem:

the controller route prefix is: `[RoutePrefix("Users")]` but it should be `[RoutePrefix("api\Users")]`

This error took me more than a day to find it...

Comment: just saw your question, I wish if i could save your time :) anyways good catch.